Derive an $O(h^4)$ five-point formula - probably misunderstood the meaning of $O(h^4)$
The problem asks us to derive an $O(h^4)$ five-point formula to approximate $f'(x_0)$ using nodes $x_0 − 2h$, $x_0 − h$, $x_0$, $x_0 + h$, $x_0 + 2h$ and here is the
solution $($I understood all of it except for the last part which I marked in blue$)$

Since it is $O(h^4)$, we can leave any terms containing $h^4$ or higher powers in the formula, then why do we still set
$$
(16a + b + d + 16e)\frac{h^4}{24} = 0?
$$
Thank you!

In theory you only need to solve the first four, but the solution might satisfy the fifth anyway. Any $o(h^4)$ function is also $O(h^4)$. This happens sometimes with these problems.

oh do you mean that solving the first four is enough but to make it better we solve for the fifth? This way the problem should ask us to find the $O(h^5)$ five-point formula, which is more precise $($I am not good at numerical analysis, so I probably missed something$)$

Just because it's $o(h^4)$ doesn't mean it's $O(h^5)$ (without further assumptions on how nice our function is).

Oh ok, thank you @MishaLavrov But to make it $O(h^4)$ why do we need the coefficient for $h^4$ to be $0$? Wouldn't it be enough for the coefficients for $h$, $h^2$ and $h^3$ to be $0$?
